# Get current node's count (rank/order?) from node.tpl in a View which renders a list of nodes

Tags: views, nodes

I have a `view` that lists multiple `article nodes`.
Now for each rendered node, I want to be able to know its rank/order from the list of displayed nodes.

Here's a visual representation:

```
[view]
    [node.tpl] $count=1 [/node.tpl]
    [node.tpl] $count=2 [/node.tpl]
    [node.tpl] $count=3 [/node.tpl]
    [node.tpl] $count=4 [/node.tpl]
    ...
[/view]
```

For the first rendered node, I will be able to access a variable called `$count` whose value is set to `1` because it's the first and so on.

Btw, I'm using Rendered entity so I'm using `node.tpl` not `views/rows` templates

Comment: Getting it in the View template is very easy (see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19207/how-do-i-get-view-the-actual-row-number), I don't know how you're going to pass that through to the node template from there though

Comment: Rows in a View already have the `.item-[n]` class. Is that enough? Do you just want a visual number or do you want to operate on it? Are you operating in PHP or Javascript?

Comment: Sorry but I'm viewing it using rendered entity hence I'm using node.tpl instead of view/rows template.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it looks like there's a similar thread but worded differently.

[How to add classes to every X number of node in a array](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24194/how-to-add-classes-to-every-x-number-of-node-in-a-array)